# How to install pyvisa 1.8 on Windows

Tags: python

I am stuck. I am trying to make `Python-Pyvisa` working on my **w10 PC**.I went back to **Python 2.7**. Then I installed **pyvisa 1.4.** Did not work.**Pyvisa 1.4** seems too old. Then I try to get version 1.8. Does not seems to be a windows version?

**Question:**
What is the (best) way to install **pyvisa 1.8** for Windows?

Please help. Thanks, Harke

Comment: What have you tried thus far? `easy_install`, `pip install pyvisa`, or downloading source and going into the directory and running `python setup.py install`

Comment: I tried "python easy_install" and "python setup.py" Both do not work. I start from directory: C:\Python27. Directories Lib and site-packages exist in right order and place. But can not be found by Python obviously. However:  a simple testfile with the line "import visa" does not give an error. Following commands I try with the resource manager stuck. It seems I have the wrong version of pyvisa (1.4) I therefore try and load version 1.8. You understand: any help very much appreciated....

Comment: Did you install the [NI-Backend](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/configuring.html)?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I added C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages to Path. then:python easy_install. Result: python can't open file 'easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file.... Doing this from the c:\....\site-packages dir gives:error: no urls, filenames or erquirements specified... I tried to understand the NI backend page..... I downloaded the pyvisa 1.8 package (tar) but upon decompressing I do not find familiar dos filenames...

Comment: Well easy_install needs an argument and doesn't need python to call it. So command would look like `easy_install pyvisa`

Comment: Thanks! I ran that. No errors. It found pyvisa 1.4. It makes no difference with respect to my simple test program: import visa; pyvisa.test(); gives pyvisa is not defined error. Then I tested: rm = visa.ResourceManager(); print(rm.list_resources()); Gives: AttributeError: 'ResourceManager' has no attribute 'list_resources' Still puzzling...What can i do more?

Comment: Getting the NI-Backend is a must, but it sounds like you are trying to skip that step. Is that true?

Comment: I have GPIB running on my W10 laptop as demonstrated by Keysight Command Expert that works with my HPIB RF power meter. That also needs the NI drivers. The hw is ok. I then want to get acces to the instruments via Python. I now have Python (64 bits) in C:\Python34. Runs. I downloaded pyvisa and created a dir: pyvisa-master in: C:\Python34\pyvisa-master. The latter dir contains a pyvisa dir with all necessary files to install pyvisa, I think. Both dirs are added to Path. I run easy_install pyvisa: no errors. python